# Kotlin expression giving different results (runtime vs IDE Evaluate expression)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging

```
val result: Boolean = aList.union(bList).any { it.something?.someOtherFlag == true }
```

I have two lists I need to join and check if any of the items has some flag set.
This has been giving me some bad results. During debugging:

1. the data before the line indicates `result = true` (`true` should be the right answer)
2. I get `result = false` by running the program
3. directly after the line, when I use the Evaluate expression tool, I get `result = true`

What is definitely NOT the problem is that **there is NO change in the data in between**.

Kotlin versions of my app/IDE plugin are different:

```
Kotlin Plugin: 203-1.5.0
App: 1.4.21
```

What I am looking for is an explanation: what can be the problem?

Comment: I would be interested to know what happens if you replace `union` with a regular list concatenation `+`. Also, how do you define the type of your elements? Are these data classes?

Comment: It would help if you shared the actual contents of the 2 lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `union` method returns a set that will keep only distinct elements, and it might discard different elements when running and when evaluating in debugger. I'm not sure how deterministic it's supposed to be, but the order could matter.

This could happen if `equals()` and/or `hashCode()` for your elements are defined without using `something`, or if `equals()`/`hashCode()` for `something`'s class is defined without using `someOtherFlag`. How are these classes defined?

Note that for `data class`es, only the properties that are present in the primary constructor are taken into account for the generated `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong, my equals didn't take `something` into account

Comment: One question though: what's the exact error here? Does `aList.union(bList)` not contain the element at runtime or is the filter not working because the compiler assumes the items are equal so there is no need to check the flag?

Comment: @Simon the return value of the `union` method is a set, so at runtime that set cannot have duplicates (and duplicates are defined by the `hashcode()`/`equals()` duo). So yeah in short `aList.union(bList)` will be missing some elements, as opposed to `aList + bList` which would keep everything. The filter is fine.